# How to track custom metrics in Application Insights from an Azure .NET Function app

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have a .NET Azure function app that initially is triggered by a timer, but that just starts a process that puts a folder in a queue. The rest of the functions in this app are queue triggered. They are essentially processing folders in Azure storage looking for files to process and placing those in another queue. An instance of one of the functions in this app is spawned for each file in the queue and it is from this function I would like to send custom metrics to Application Insights.

This function evaluates the file and will determine one of 4 things it should do with the file. There can be hundreds instances of this function running simultaneously.

I want to track this data, essentially wanting to see in a given time period how many required action one, how many action two, and so on.

The results of this data gathering for a given run should be something like this:

- Files processed: 894
- Files new: 793
- Files Changed: 25
- Files Cleaned Up: 74

So I'm essentially wanting to tick up multiple counters.

Here are the two main documents I have been referencing:

- [Application Insights API for custom events and metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#getmetric)
- [Custom metric collection in .NET and .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/get-metric)

I understand the key point that I don't want to transmit telemetry data from each instance of this function directly to AI as that would be costly in resources, so the use of GetMetric() is the recommended course. That said, the examples involve creating a TelemtryClient in a context that can be referenced by all the code that needs to report data but I'm unsure of how I can do this effectively and efficiently within such a highly parallel function app.

I would love to find that there is a fairly straightforward pattern for this that does not involve some kind of singleton/durable function but that might be the only way.

To be more specific on the code front, here is the general structure:

- Timmer Function

  - When triggered, puts one or more primary folders (PF) in a primary processing queue (PPQ)
- Primary Folder Function

  - Triggered by the PPQ.
  - Processes all subfolders (SF) of the PF
  - SF's are placed into a SF queue (SFQ)
  - Files are placed into the file queue (FQ)
- Subfolder Function

  - Triggered by the SFQ
  - Processes contents of subfolder (SF)
  - New subfolders are placed into a SF queue (SFQ)
  - Files are placed into the file queue (FQ)
- Folder Function (FF)

  - Triggered by the FQ
  - Processes a given file
  - Primary point I want to transmit one or more results to tick a counter(s)

The only thing I have tried was writing data directly from timer triggered test function in my app just to see the Application Insights part working.

```c#
    public class FunctionTesting
    {
        private readonly TelemetryClient telemetryClient;

        public FunctionTesting(TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfiguration)
        {
            this.telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);
        }
        [FunctionName("FunctionTesting")]
        public async Task Run(
            [TimerTrigger("*/5 * * * * *")] TimerInfo timer,
            ExecutionContext context,
            ILogger log)
        {
            // Generate a random number between 1 and 100
            var random = new Random();
            var num = random.Next(1, 101);

            // Log the number to Application Insights
          
            this.telemetryClient.TrackMetric("RandomNumber", num);

            // Check if the number is even or odd, and less than or greater than 50
            if (num % 2 == 0)
            {
                this.telemetryClient.TrackEvent("EvenNumber");
            }
            else
            {
                this.telemetryClient.TrackEvent("OddNumber");
            }

            if (num < 50)
            {
                this.telemetryClient.TrackEvent("LessThan50");
            }
            else
            {
                this.telemetryClient.TrackEvent("GreaterThan50");
            }

            log.LogInformation($"Generated random number: {num}");
        }
    }
}
```

My plan, if I'm able to find a pattern that would work is to implement/test it in this test function before adding it to the rest of my code.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you help explain this line ... `wanting to see in a given time period how many required action one, how many action two, and so on.` ?  Are you trying to see how many actions were required for each file?

Comment: A run of this app will process thousands of files, just for reference, all in 30-60 min.
I'm looking for a count of facts/actions, either for the entire run, or just over time. A single instance of the File Processor will record 2-4 such counts.
Things like: Does the file exist in the archive, does it need to be replaced...things like that.
My understanding is that GetMetric will aggregate such info and flush the cash every so often.

Comment: Just for further information for the curious, this solution is archiving files between storage accounts and due to the load involved, and even with async processing, things sometimes timeout. The files was copied, but did not return a success in time to avoid the function instance from timing out. Due to this, the source file is not removed. The file will be found again to process, will see the file is already archived, will compare the md5's and then will remove the source.
Each of those facts are examples of things I want to track, but as efficiently and with as little cost as possible.

Comment: If this is the problem `find that there is a fairly straightforward pattern for this that does not involve some kind of singleton/durable function but that might be the only way.`   Then, yes, using int/counters is faster, but I think the self-requirement for telemetry client is creating this "problem" for you.  What's wrong with using basic ILogger messages like "moved {filename} from {folderA} to {folderB}" or "created queue item, {queueitem}"?  You can aggregate those actions in AI using KUSTO and KQL.

Comment: Put another way - Move your aggregation from app-side to AI-side and there is no need to be concerned about singleton / durable function patterns.  Less code, less complexity. Yes, learn KQL (KUSTO) = https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/tutorial?pivots=azuredataexplorer

Comment: Cost is one key point. My application runs 1.5-2 Mil instances in a month, maybe more. Before I made some changes, it was costing us 200-300 a month for processing/storage in Application Insights. This is why I am taking to heart the Pre-aggregating vs non pre-aggregating API section in Custom metric collection in .NET, linked above.

Comment: A very important key to engaging and surviving moving workloads to the cloud is the way and degree to witch you go Cloud Native. I think of this topic as a good example of this ideal. Even though I'm already working in functions, you can still employ patterns that can be costly and inefficient in how they engage the options and systems available.

Comment: Troy,
Did not mean to seem preachy in that last comment. :-) I had not taken the chance to actually look up your background yet. My length and depth of experience both in Azure and functions is limited, I'm trying to really take to heart how I'm part of what is laying the groundwork for how we are moving into the cloud so I'm VERY conscious of cost and efficiency. Very open to suggestions though.

Comment: No worries.  I'm just an engineer like yourself with a bit more experience on Azure side.  I can see how not answering the question directly by providing a `fairly straightforward pattern for this` because well, that could be very opinion based?  I'm still ducking a bit, but I would say *quantify the cost difference between pre and post-aggregation*? If we're being VERY cost conscious there are a few options to employ before diving into patterns that might add complexity.  https://medium.com/@beyerleinf/azure-application-insights-how-not-to-burn-money-using-it-5f1bbe5816b4

Comment: Put another way - you can REALLY drive costs down with Code-based monitoring patterns mentioned in that article.  The suggestions there should address your need for a known, cost-effective pattern, that doesn't involve singleton or durable function.

Comment: Have not dived in to that article yet, but very hopeful and very grateful!
Part of my take on this is that I have little interest in trying to save money by being lazy or to simple, by that mainly meaning just avoiding things based on risk, like trying to just leave AA alone.

Comment: AA is just too valuable as a tool to not just troubleshoot a function while you are fine tuning it through initial iterations, but I'm convinced it is could be key to not being blindsided by changes in how your function runs long term. While it should be very helpful in catching issues due to changes in your data/environment, it will also likely catch changes MS makes to the function architecture that you might not have caught that are impacting your app, even in just the efficiency/cost side.

Comment: In digesting the article @TroyWitthoeft linked to, the first option was already something I was doing. I have a few settings in my host.json config, the most effective one being enableDependencyTracking set to false. Took me a bit to find that, but one of the biggest issues for me WAS dependency tracking.